# Pass a jQuery variable to a string

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery object called `window.offset`.

This object has another object called `search`.

It has two values, `top` & `left`.

Eg:

```
window.offset.search = {top:200, left:150}
```

I want to pass this 'search' object as a variable called 'id'.

How to pass this variable to the `window.offset` object and get the `top` & `left` value.

I tried as this. But it doesn't work.

```
var offset = 'window.offset.'+id

console.log(offset.left); //undefined
```

Comment: `window.offset[id] = window.offset.search` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do :

```
var id = "search";
var offset = window.offset[id];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to eval the string:

```
var myOffset = eval(offset);
console.log(myOffset.left);
```

Comment: Your answer also correct. That is a alter method. Thanks for teach me new thing.